# Athena: compare columns consisting array<strings> in two different tables

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have 2 external tables (parquet files in S3) in Athena, each of them has a column which is array of strings. One of the tables is a subset and I need to compare these array values with the other table having the superset array. I believe the problem would be clearer with the below illustration. Both tables do not have any duplicate records.

```
Table 1 (Sample Subset table)
+---+-----------+---------------------------+
|no | prod_name |   article_list            |
+---+-----------+---------------------------+
| 1 |sofa       | ['ABC','PQR']             |
| 2 |cupboard   | ['LMN','DEF','XYZ']       |
| 3 |table      | ['DEF']                   |
| 4 |chair      | ['DEF','PQR','ABC']       |
| 5 |dresser    | ['LMN','IJK','WXY','STU'] |
+---+--------------------+------------------+

Table 2 (Sample Superset table)
+---+---------+--------------+---------------------------------------------------+
|no | wh_code | restock_date | article_list                                      |
+---+---------+--------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| 1 |WH0001   | 2020-01-12   | ['ABC','BCE','CDE','DEF','JKL','PQR','QRS','STU'] |
| 2 |WH0001   | 2020-04-15   | ['ABC','CDE','DEF','IJK','LMN','PQR','STU','XYZ'] |
| 3 |WH0002   | 2021-03-17   | ['BCE','DEF','IJK','LMN','PQR','RST','STU','WXY'] |
| 4 |WH0003   | 2021-08-20   | ['ABC','IJK','LMN','NOP','PQR','RST','STU','WXY'] |
| 5 |WH0003   | 2022-03-26   | ['DEF','IJK','LMN','NOP','PQR','RST','STU','XYZ'] |
+---+---------+--------------+---------------------------------------------------+

Required result
+------------------------+---------+-----------------+
|article_list (table 1)  | wh_code | restock_date    |
+---+--------------------+---------------------------+
| ['ABC','PQR']          | WH0001  | 2020-01-12      |
| ['ABC','PQR']          | WH0001  | 2020-04-15      |
| ['ABC','PQR']          | WH0003  | 2021-08-20      |
| ['LMN','DEF','XYZ']    | WH0001  | 2020-04-15      |
| ['LMN','DEF','XYZ']    | WH0003  | 2021-08-20      |
| ['DEF']                | WH0001  | 2020-01-12      |
| ['DEF']                | WH0001  | 2020-04-15      |
| ['DEF']                | WH0002  | 2021-03-17      |
| ['DEF']                | WH0003  | 2022-03-26      | 
| .                      | .       | .               |
| .                      | .       | .               |
| .                      | .       | .               |
+------------------------+---------+-----------------+
```

The following query in Athena works to find a particular combination (['ABC', 'PQR']) in table 2 consisting of the superset array. It results in the first 3 rows of the required result.

```
SELECT ['ABC', 'PQR'] as article_list, 
    wh_code, 
    restock_date 
FROM "table_2" 
WHERE filter(ARRAY ['ABC', 'PQR'], x -> NOT CONTAINS(article_list, x)) = ARRAY[] 
group by wh_code, restock_date
```

Request help to write a generic query (considering all the combinations from table 1) to get the desired result

Answer (score 1):

Join the two table on the required condition. Also it seems that you should consider using [`array_except`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#array_except) to simplify the query (also I use `cardinality` to count number of elements):

```sql
-- sample data
with table1(no, prod_name, article_list ) as (
    values ( 1, 'sofa', array['ABC','PQR']),
           ( 2, 'cupboard', array['LMN','DEF','XYZ'] )
),
table2 (no, wh_code, restock_date, article_list) as (
    values (1, 'WH0001', date '2020-01-12', array['ABC','BCE','CDE','DEF','JKL','PQR','QRS','STU']),
        (2, 'WH0001', date '2020-04-15', array['ABC','CDE','DEF','IJK','LMN','PQR','STU','XYZ']),
        (3, 'WH0002', date '2021-03-17', array['BCE','DEF','IJK','LMN','PQR','RST','STU','WXY']),
        (4, 'WH0003', date '2021-08-20', array['ABC','IJK','LMN','NOP','PQR','RST','STU','WXY'])
)

-- query
select t1.article_list, t2.wh_code, t2.restock_date
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on cardinality(array_except(t1.article_list, t2.article_list)) = 0;
```

Output:

| article_list | wh_code | restock_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [ABC, PQR] | WH0001 | 2020-01-12 |
| [ABC, PQR] | WH0001 | 2020-04-15 |
| [ABC, PQR] | WH0003 | 2021-08-20 |
| [LMN, DEF, XYZ] | WH0001 | 2020-04-15 |

**UPD**

Try next one, but taking in account size of the data maybe you will need to partition the queries:

```sql
-- query
select arbitrary(article_list), wh_code, restock_date
from (select no, article_list, article
    from table1, unnest (article_list) as t(article)) as t1
join (select no, wh_code, restock_date, article
    from table2, unnest (article_list) as t(article)) as t2 on t1.article = t2.article
group by t1.no, wh_code, restock_date
having count(t1.article) = cardinality(arbitrary(article_list));
```

Comment: Thanks for the above solution @Guru. The thing is the above table 2 has more than a million records and running the above query is taking a long time (>30 mins). Is there a more performance optimised way of solving the above problem.

Comment: @Vortex possibly unnesting arrays and joining will be able to speed up the query due to possibility of using the hash (or another faster one) search of strings. I will try to make demo query, but not earlier then tomorrow.

Comment: @Vortex try new one. But not sure if it is better or worse)